# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable on discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands

token = 'token goess here'

client = commands.bot(command_prefix = '__')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')

client.run(token)
```

The code works fine before, and now I am getting a "TypeError: 'module' is not callable" error
I can't find what is wrong with my code so...any idea what went wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```py
client = commands.bot(command_prefix = '__')
```

to

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '__')
```

`discord.ext.commands` contains `bot.py` module which causes the error you're getting, you're looking for a `Bot` class exposed by that module.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, it's working now. but I still wondering why the code work in the first time i run it tho...